# How to correctly await zmq response from within an async route

Tags: python-3.x, async-await, zeromq, starlette

I am attempting to wait for a ZMQ message response from within a route but am getting the following error.

`RuntimeError: Task got bad yield: <zmq.eventloop.future._TornadoFuture object at 0x7f74f4143c88>`

The following code worked with ApiStar on an earlier version of our API coded against that framework but we have made a decision to move to Starlette now. The code below is included in a `async def` function.

```
import zmq
from zmq.eventloop.future import Context
import threading
zmq_context = zmq.eventloop.future.Context()
mysocket = zmq_context.socket(zmq.SUB)

mysocket.connect(f"tcp://{DB_HOST}:{DEFAULT_ZMQ_PORT}")

topicstring = 'niOSGOV6eAyUKOOVdXm0CA=='
topicfilter=bytes(topicstring, 'utf-8').decode()
mysocket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, topicfilter)

all_responses = await mysocket.recv_multipart(flags=0, copy=True, track=False)
```

Thank you for any assistance!